# Swift: Int is not convertible to '@lvalue inout _'

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I declare the context and key variables outside the UIViewController class

```
// player item contexts
private let PlayerItemStatusContext = 0

// player item keys
private let PlayerItemStatusKey = "status"
...
if status == AVKeyValueStatus.Loaded {
                self.playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
                self.playerItem?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: PlayerItemStatusKey, options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.Initial, context: &PlayerItemStatusContext)
                //self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: self.playerItem!)
                //self.previewView.layer = self.player

            }
```

The addobserver line keeps throwing the error: 'Int' is not convertible to '@lvalue inout _'  I don't understand this and have no idea how to fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The context has to be a `var`. You can't pass a `let` as an `inout` parameter.